# Can't access XAMPP after changing iptables

Tags: centos, xampp

I've been working on a web application in a  CentOS 7 machine and testing it in a Windows machine. Both machines are in a LAN network and I have access to the centos machine using VNC viewer and sometimes putty.

I've been trying to access the CentOS 7 machine using FileZilla to try and send files to a specific location. However, after I added to `iptables.conf` the following line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

And then restarting both iptables and ip6tables.

```
# systemctl restart iptables
# systemctl restart ip6tables
```

I can no longer access my web app (via browser), or connect to my ftp server through the browser or Windows Explorer.

I’ve set `iptables` back to the way it was and restarted both `iptables` and `ip6tables`. I've restarted XAMPP as well and I still can't access anything from it, from my Windows machine. But both VNC and Putty work fine. Can anyone tell me how I can regain access to XAMPP? I clearly changed something and have no idea how to find it and fix it.

Comment: It sounds like the rule to access your webapp may not have been in the config file (was added temporarily), so you may need to add e.g. `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. It would be helpful if you posted the output of `iptables -nvL` and the IP addresses in question.

Comment: If you already had FTP access with Windows explorer, why would you add that rule at all? Filezilla also does FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend flushing out all `iptables` rules to see if you can even connect without a firewall in place like this:

```
sudo iptables -F
```

If you can connect without `iptables` rules then `iptables` is definitely mucking up the works. And if `iptables` is indeed mucking up the works, then I would recommend taking a closer look at the port 21 rul you just set.

I’m unsure about why you have `--state NEW` setup in your command:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

That’s generally used only with a related rule check higher up in the chain. If you do not have rule check logic in place, I believe the network connecting will always wait for a “NEW” connection which can essentially be forever if there is already a connection in place.

Instead, I would recommend this simpler version of the same concept:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, it seems like you need to have port 20 open as well on the `OUTPUT` chain [according to this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/38425/100013).

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
```